# How do I save a Ext.XTemplate into the DOM when using Rowexpander in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having a strange issue with the RowExpander plugin inside of my Ext.grid.Panel component. FYI this grid is backed by a Ext.data.BufferedStore component to handed the data via a REST Api

So I'm dynamically loading in values from an Ajax when the user clicks on the expand button, the row opens and makes an Ajax call using the expandbody event method.

That works great with no issues.

The problem is that when I scroll down the the page, the table rows that were open lose all thier data.

Here is my set up:

```
// Create Basic Ext Grid
    var oDataGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'oData Entity Table',
        store: oDataStore,
        height: 450,
        id: 'odataGrid',
        loadMask: true,
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            enableCaching: false,
            id: 'odataTableRowPlugin',

            rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div id="oData-Inner-Table-Row-{Id}" ><button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Loading...</button></div>')
        }],
        viewConfig:{
          listeners:{
              expandbody: function(__rowNode, __record, __expandRow, __eOpts){ 

              var _rowId = __record.get('Id');
              var _targetId = 'oData-Inner-Table-Row-' + _rowId;
              var _finalUrl = _that._URLROOT +'/odata/' + _that._ENTITYTYPE;

              var _qb = new OData.QueryBuilder(_finalUrl);
              var _type = OData.INT32;
              var _operator = OData.EQUALS;
              var _filter = 'Id';

              _qb.addWhereFilter('id_'+_rowId, _type, _filter, _operator, _rowId);
              var _query = _qb.generateQueryUrl();

              // Include Expand NavProps
              _query = _query + _that.createExpandedUrl();

              _that.grabEntityObject(_query,_targetId);
            }
          }

        },

        renderTo: 'oData-grid'
    });
```

So even though the row has been updated the information doesn't seem to be saved into the dom or something.

Any thoughts clues, suggestions, etc?

Comment: You cannot save data in the grid's DOM, because the buffered store and the buffered renderer will rebuild the dom dynamically.

Comment: Damn, any ideas then? Is there a way to collapse the row then when the user scrolls?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't cache the data on the model? Then, you can fetch it the first time, or otherwise just use it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli with a buffered store, this won't work, because the buffered store doesn't even keep all the records.

Comment: It will in a per record basis, I don't see how it's any different if you attach the data to the record.

Comment: I am unable to attach the data to the record per a requirement by the product owner. Anyhow thanks for the feedback. I'll have to look for another solution